# Find the m-th smallest number in Matlab?

Tags: matlab

Is there an efficient way to find the m-th smallest number in a vector of length n in Matlab? Do I have to use sort() function? Thanks and regards!

Comment: Please see KTHVALUE on matlab's file exchange: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23195. See also Min/Max selection: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/23576

Comment: This is not a duplicate of finding all n-smallest elements. That task almost always requires a sort to be efficient, but this one  can be done in linear time as per the answers below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit 2**: As Eitan pointed the first part of the answer doesn't address the question of finding the smallest m-th value but regarding the m-th element after the min value. The rest of the answer remains... +1 for Eitan's sharpness.

<strike>While `sort` is probably very efficient to begin with, you can try to see whether a `find` will be better. For example:</strike>

```
id=find(X>min(X),m,'first');
id(end) % is the index of the smallest m-th element in X
```

the function `find` has added functionality that lets you find the 'first' or 'last' elements that meet some criterion. For example, if you want to find the first `n` elements in array `X` less than a value `y`, use  `find(X<y,n,'first')`

This operation stops as soon as the first element meeting the condition is encountered, which can result in significant time savings if the array is large and the value you find happens to be far from the end.

I'd also like to recap what @woodchips said already in [this SO discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019975/how-to-speed-up-sort-function-in-matlab) that is somewhat relevant to your question:

The best way to speed up basic built-in algorithms such as sort is to get a faster hardware. It will speed everything else up too.  MATLAB is already doing that in an efficient manner, using an optimized code internally. Saying this, maybe a GPU add-on can improve this too...

**Edit:**
For what it's worth, adding to Muster's comment, there is a FEX file called [nth_element](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/29453-nthelement) that is a MEX wrap of C++  that will get a solution in `O(n)` time for what you need. (similar to what @DDD pointed to)

Comment: This finds the first _m_ indices of numbers that are greater than the minimum, but they do not necessarily include the _m_-th smallest number, which is what being asked for in the question (maybe I'm misinterpreting the question wrong?)

Comment: well, in my answer `id(end)` is the index of the smallest m-th element in X. I assumed that going from there to obtaining the value `X(id(end))` is obvious.

Comment: That's not what I meant. I meant that the _m_-th value in `X` that is larger than `min(X)` is not necessarily the _m_-th smallest number in `X`. For example, take `m = 2` and `X = [9 9 1 2]`. Your solution produces 9, and I believe the correct answer is 2.

Comment: I see now what you're saying.. hmmm. yes I confused index to value. I'll edit my answer shortly. Thanks Eitan.

Answer (score 7):

You don't need to sort the list of numbers to find the **m<sup>th</sup>** smallest number. The **m<sup>th</sup>** smallest number can be found out in linear time. i.e. if there are `n` elements in your array you can get a solution in `O(n)` time by using the selection algorithm and median of median algorithm.

The link is to the Wikipedia article,

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Selection_algorithm#Linear_general_selection_algorithm_-_Median_of_Medians_algorithm

Answer (score 1):

As alternative solution, you may follow this way:

```
A = randi(100,4000,1);
A = sort(A,'ascend');
m = 5; % the 5 smallest numbers in array A
B = A(1:5);
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: OP was looking for alternatives for this method..

Comment: @GuntherStruyf:   OP asked: "do I have have to use `sort`?" which does not directly implies alternative methods.

Comment: Imo it implies that he already knew how to use sort, which is pretty straightforward anyway.